# Как можно добавить логотип в выбранное место в Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModel"
     x:Class="App1.View.LoginPage" BackgroundColor="#f0f2f5">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:LoginViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="50" WidthRequest="396" HeightRequest="430" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" >
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Вход на Lockdown" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Title" Margin="0,30,0,10" />
            <Entry  Placeholder="Логин" x:Name="login" Text="{Binding Login}" />
            <Entry Placeholder="Пароль" x:Name ="password" Text="{Binding Password}"  IsPassword="True"/>
            <Label x:Name="LoginMessageLabel" Text="{Binding LoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" IsVisible="{Binding TurnLoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextColor="Red"></Label>
            <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Вход" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#1877F2" Margin="10,10,10,10"
            Command="{Binding cmdLogin}">

            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="createAccount" Text="Создать новый аккаунт" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#42B72A" Margin="10,10,10,10" Command="{Binding cmdCreateAccount}"/>
            <Label Text="Забыли пароль?" TextColor="#1877F2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding cmdForgotPassword}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

Хочу добавить туда,как указано на фото,только не знаю как можно это сделать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заверните Frame в еще один StackLayout и над ним в рвзметке добавьте то что нужно.

Comment: т.е сверху фрейма еще один Stacklayout,а куда надо добавить Image,между Stacklayout и Frame?